# How to access a variable declared in a module?

Tags: ios, module, lua, coronasdk

in my game.lua file I have:

```
local sprites = require("sprites.lua")
```

sprites.lua contains

```
local iceberg = display.newImage("iceberg.png")
iceberg.x = _W/2
iceberg.y = _H/2
iceberg.alpha = 1
```

Now, I'd like to set "iceberg.alpha" to 0 from "game.lua", but If I try, Corona returns "attempt to index global iceberg (a nil value)"

Of course, sprites.lua contains

```
module(..., package.seeall)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've even tried to use sprites.iceberg.alpha = 0, but obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: We will need more of the code from sprites.lua, especially around the return statement

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `module`. Simply return `iceberg` value in `sprites.lua` or whatever other value you want to access:

```
-- sprites.lua
local iceberg = display.newImage("iceberg.png")
iceberg.x = _W/2
iceberg.y = _H/2
iceberg.alpha = 1
return iceberg

-- game.lua
local iceberg = require("sprites.lua")
-- iceberg.alpha is available here
```

[Lua modules](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) tutorial has some additional information on how this works and more references.

Comment: Thank you Paul, but it still doesn't work, in my "game.lua" I have

local function startNewGame(event)
 if(event.phase=="ended")then
  iceberg.alpha = 1
 end
end

startBTN:addEventListener("touch", startNewGame)

Comment: Check the value of iceberg.alpha in that "if" statement in a debugger or post a complete example. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey sorry I probably did some mistakes, cause know it is working perfectly.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variable is not local. Look at this example which works fine.

Say in the following codes if you use

```
local star = display.newLine( 200, 90, 227, 165 )
```

in the test.lua then you will get the error message.

This is "main.lua". Try changing alpha values.

```
require "test"
star.alpha=0.5
```

This is "test.lua".

```
star = display.newLine( 200, 90, 227, 165 )
star.anchorX = 0.2257
star.anchorY = 0.5

star.x = display.contentCenterX 
star.y = display.contentCenterY
local function rotate(x)
 timer.performWithDelay(1, function() star.rotation = star.rotation + 5;end, 15)
end
rotate()
```